# How to override Ruby + method?

Tags: ruby

Just for learning purpose I am trying to override the Ruby + method, but I am not getting the desired output.

```
class Integer
  def +(my_num)
    "Plus method overridden"
  end
end

puts 5.+(9)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What are you expecting? The output is: `Plus method overridden`

Comment: I am getting the output: 14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you use ruby < 2.4. If so you want to patch `Fixnum` and not `Integer`. Be careful as the system itself uses numbers as well.

```
class Fixnum
  alias_method :add, :+

  def +(other)
    puts 'plus method overridden'
    add(other)
  end
end

puts 5 + 9
```

Comment: Worth mentioning:


`2.3.3 :001 > 2.class #=> Fixnum` and 

 `2.3.3 :002 > Fixnum.ancestors #=> [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Comment: Good answer. For consistency I suggest you change `add(other)` to `puts add(other)`, change `puts 5 + 9` to `5+9` and show what that causes to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby Language Specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) allows `Integer` to have implementation-specific subclasses. See Section 15.2.8.1, lines 27-33.

It looks like your implementation does have such subclasses. In that case, the `+` method may be overridden in a subclass.

My best guess is that you have an implementation which distinguishes between `Fixnum`s and `Bignum`s, and that our `Integer#+` gets overridden by `Fixnum#+`.

By the way, even if what you were trying to do were working, it wouldn't be *overriding*, it would be *overwriting*.

Also note that if what you were trying to do were working, you would have most likely broken your Ruby process, since `Integer`s are fundamental and widely-used all over the place in Ruby.